# Business rule engine to inject to ETL job (Pentaho)

Tags: pentaho, etl, rule, business-rules

We are using Pentaho as ETL tool, database is Oracle.

And we want the give the power of defining business rules to the end user, which will execute the given transformations in selected phases of the ETL.

So a user will define some rules on a UI.  I will create a UI with many dropdowns to define certain type of rules, for ex.:

"Range" rule, a column should be in that range

"Not null" rule: If a  field value is null change it to UNKNOWN or

"Count rule" if a total number of rows increased by given percentage stop the ETL
etc.
Those rules  will be injected to the ETL job. We cant hard code rules.

I tried to use Drools under Pentaho but the documentation is almost non-existent (For the use under Pentaho), 
So I decided  to implement the Rule Engine myself:
I will create a UI , which basically will allow to define business rules and those will be converted to SQL statements and stored in database.And in Pentaho there is something called Execute Row Script step, which allows to execute sql statements stored in a table.

The idea creating business rules as SQL statements seems not so good but I dont have any other choice based on my research.

Do you know any tool that would create business rules as SQL?  Any advice overall?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to implement business rules in PDI, i recently built my own home grown system too. It was pretty complex but we ended up with pluggable templates, metadata injection and totally metadata driven. Nice!  (Written 99% in PDI and 1% in java)

Drools is not so good because it's terribly slow. That is a combined feature of drools itself, and the PDI drools integration not being too hot.

There are some other alternatives though you could check out JARE written by a colleague of mine - which comes with a UI etc and is built from the ground up to work with (but not exclusively) PDI. See details here: https://github.com/uwegeercken/jareplugin

To find details of the extensive framework I built you can see my talk at Skillsmatter: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5115-how-amia-used-pentaho

Comment: Thanks We are not planning to have a very complex rule engine.I briefly looked at the video, so you are using user defined Java Expressions with Metadata injection? 
The metadata injection part seemed a bit long time work , is that right? Thanks

Comment: Yes we are - we are injecting via code. Calling the kettle API directly. However in the latest version of PDI 5.2 that step supports native metadata injection so its much easier. Matt casters and Diethard Steiner have good metadata injection blog posts.

Comment: I also have a sample whereby you can evaluate SQL snippets natively in PDI. I should blog that one day!

Answer (score 0):

Execute Row Script step is pretty useful if you can manage it.

Ok, sometimes I limit scalability in order to get as more simple as I can.

**How?**

Excel tables (or Google Spreadsheet):

Make a table for users where they can input fields and rules. Limit possible inputs and give them a minimum chances to make a mistake (dropdowns as you already mentioned). Yes, they do not have endless possibilities but make sure that it will suit all their needs + 20%.

example: In my case, end users had maximum 3 date ranges (between this and this or between this2 and this2 or between this3 and this3) for date field. They always used one.

It's not too hard to make SQL Query from your row, inside worksheet (excel formula). Collect only SQL Query column and execute it. It's hidden column for end-users.